# Binary Python module import Error on Heroku: ImportError: /app/mylib.so: undefined symbol: _PyGC_generation0

Tags: python, heroku, server, paas, nuitka

### What I've done

- Compiled `mylib.py` -> `mylib.so` using Python 3.6 + Nuitka 0.6.5
- Added `mylib.so` to Heroku app and deployed to Heroku
- My app did not run on Heroku server
- So I entered to Heroku bash and tried to import `mylib` manually

### The error

```
$ heroku run bash
~ $ ls
app.json  app.py  mylib.so  Procfile  README.md  requirements.txt  runtime.txt
~ $ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 21:35:17) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mylib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /app/mylib.so: undefined symbol: _PyGC_generation0
>>>
```

### Question

- Why do I get this error?
- If Heroku is not capable for Nuitka-compiled binaries, is there any alternative free service?

Comment: The problem was that I compiled `mylib.py` on Python 3.6.9 and Heroku Python version was 3.7.3

Comment: I modified `runtime.txt` to set Heroku Python version as 3.6.10. So the error vanished, but I'm still not clear what `_PyGC_generation` was. So, I am waiting for answers.